# Ubuntu folder permission, running WordPress on nginx

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, permissions, file-permissions

I have a very mysterious problem with permission on nginx/ubuntu VPS.

I keep getting the following error, when using media upload on wordpress:

> “asr.jpg” has failed to upload due to an error Unable to create
>   directory uploads/2014/02. Is its parent directory writable by the
>   server?

But, here are my uploads folder settings, which states that `www-data` is the owner, I've also checked that WordPress is running as `www-data` user:

`drwxrwxr-x  8 www-data www-data 4096 Feb  6 14:41 uploads`

Any suggestions please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The issue was tedious WordPress settings oversight. Completely forgot to check `uploads` folder location after server migration; check for upload folder setting under `Settings/Media`.